# Screen streching and shifting

Tags: display, xrandr, display-resolution

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on my secondary computer. It has a MSI FM2-A55M-E33 motherboard and a AMD CPU, running off of the integrated graphics. It's currently hooked up to a HP 2009m monitor, and that's the problem. The monitor is 1600x900 @ 60hz, with an aspect ratio of 16:9. When I switch to that in the display settings, the display is shifted down about a half-inch, and it stretches off the right side by about 4 inches. Right now I'm using it with a resolution of 1280x1024 @ 60hz, with an aspect ratio of 5:4, and the entire screen is horizontally stretched so that everything is much wider than it should be. What should I do to make it so that I can use it at the default resolution of 1600x900, where nothing is stretched?